# Select all records from one table not in another table based on a condition

Tags: sql, hive

I have a customers table `t1` which looks like this:

```
cust_id    cust_zip
   1000      19999
   2000      29999
   4000      39999
   5000      89999
```

I have a transactions table `t2` that looks like this:

```
store_id    cust_id    cust_zip
     100       1000       19999
     100       2000       29999
     100       3000       39999
```

I'm trying to pull `t2.store_id`, `t2.cust_zip` and `t1.cust_id` into one table where:

1. the `cust_zip` field matches
2. `cust_id` field does not match

The result I'm looking for is:

```
store_id    cust_zip    cust_id
     100       39999       4000
```

In this example, `cust_id` `5000` is not pulled from `t1` because the associated `cust_zip` `89999` is not associated with `store_id` `100` in `t2`. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a simple conditional join?

```
Select t2.store_id,t2.cust_zip,t1.cust_id
from t2
join t1 on t2.cust_zip=t1.cust_zip and t2.cust_id<>t1.cust_id
```

I do wonder though why your database is not normalized. I would think transaction table would probably have store_zip then you are trying to match store zip with customer zip

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a JOIN and a WHERE query. Something like this: (query might be different depending on your SQL dialect)

```
SELECT t2.store_id, t2.cust_zip, t1.cust_id FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.cust_zip = t2.cust_zip
WHERE t1.cust_zip = t2.cust_zip AND
      t1.cust_id != t2.cust_id
```

Comment: Repeating the `t1.cust_zip = t2.cust_zip` condition is not necessary. You can even go without a `WHERE` clause and simple add `AND t1.cust_id != t2.cust_id` to the `ON` clause.